# VaulueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) Django 3.2.5

Tags: python, django

I have an orders model that displays the order status as a dropdown in the Django admin panel.

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Out for Delivery', 'Out for Delivery'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
    )
    customers = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    products = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

And I am rendering the models in the dashboard view

```
def dashboard_view(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.all()
    orders = Orders.objects.all()

    total_customers = customers.count()
    total_orders = orders.count()
    delivered = orders.filter('Delivered').count()
    pending = orders.filter('Pending').count()

    context = {'customers': customers, 'orders': orders,'total_orders': total_orders,
               'delivered': delivered, 'pending': pending}

    return render(request, "account/dashboard.html", context)
```

while filtering the string 'Delivered' from class Orders, Django throws me a ValueError saying that 'too many values to unpack (expected 2)'

This is my first Django implementation, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid filter string. You need to give it a column and a value, e.g. `Delivered=1`, otherwise what filter is it meant to be applying?

Comment: I think your response helped, I tried doing, orders.filter(status='Delivered').count() and I was able to solve the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @TheReactor said the problem is that you are passing one value to the `filter` where is required a `key=value` that you want to filter:

You have to change the following lines:

```
delivered = orders.filter(status='Delivered').count()
pending = orders.filter(status='Pending').count()
```

That's will do the work.